# React Router stopped working after git merge

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to troubleshoot my react router. It is going to a blank page and not loading the component when hitting the route. I merged some code, and I thought it was missing react-router-dom, but I reinstalled and it appears to be loaded. I wasn't getting any errors in my code either. I feel like it might have something to do with the history or router because on the PrivateMainLayout, it loads, but I have to refresh to get it to work, direct urls do not go to the route either. Here is my code for react router for my login if it helps:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter,Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateMainLayout from '../layouts/PrivateMainLayout';
import AuthenticatedRoute from '../AuthenticatedRoute';
import Login from '../pages/Login';

export class LoginLayout extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/bis/login" exact component={Login}/>
                        <AuthenticatedRoute login={this.props.login} path="/bis" component={PrivateMainLayout}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        login: state.login
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(LoginLayout);
```

Let me know if you have ideas on why this behavior may be happening. TIA.

Comment: Remove the export from `export class LoginLayout`

Comment: Another thing that helps direct urls is setting a `base` element in your index.html.

Comment: took out export from class LoginLayout. Didn't fix the problem, but yes that should not have been in there. Also, not sure what is meant by "setting a base element"?

Comment: I think it is something to do with my nginx paths

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough adding

```
location /bis {
    try_files $uri /bis/index.html;
}
```

Into nginx fixes my problem. I forgot I had that in there.